# setting up __DIR__ path in php

Tags: php, html, zend-framework

Here is is `output` of my directory path

```
echo(__DIR__);
```

**/Users/tsrinivas/www/Album/module/photos/view/photos/photos**

but i want to point `4` directories before,output should look something like.

**/Users/tsrinivas/www/Album/public/images/upload/**

how to achieve this?

Comment: Why not define your base directory and reference everything from there

Comment: Use [`dirname()`](http://php.net/dirname). Also, beware of [`open_basedir`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir) php setting.

Answer (score 0):

You can traverse the directory tree using `..` down 5 blocks and add the rest of your path

```
$path = __DIR__ . "../../../../../public/images/upload/";
```

or place `__DIR__` in a file that is located in `/Users/tsrinivas/www/Album/public/images/upload/`